# Why do the controlled unitary operations in quantum phase estimation have $2^n$ in their exponents?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, measurement, quantum-phase-estimation

Why do the unitary gates on the measurement qubits have $2^n$?  Why do we need to apply the unitary gates for any power at all?  What would happen if we applied the controlled-$U$ only once, for example, for each control qubit, prior to the inverse QFT?

For example, from Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_phase_estimation_algorithm).

Specifically the [circuit diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_phase_estimation_algorithm#/media/File:PhaseCircuit-crop.svg) illustrated in Wikipedia.

Another resource that shows this is the Qiskit [documentation](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-phase-estimation.html).

Comment: Is your question why $2^n$ as opposed to some other power?  The QFT factors nicely to determine a *binary* representation of the phase.  Remember we also like to pad the (classical) FFT to a power of $2$.  Cooley and Tukey (rediscovering the work of Gauss) .

Comment: Why a power at all? Why not just U with no power for all unitary gates?

Comment: @mikanim if you apply $U$ just once you will only learn one bit of the phase... not so useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also struggled with this question initially and I understood it really well after looking through these set of slides starting at "Quantum Phase Estimation" (page 120 in the pdf): https://drive.google.com/file/d/14G_0TwdxBFpI_Ylj5lb_imVtcnunrQcB/view?usp=sharing

But the short answer is that for every extra level of accuracy in binary, you need an extra power of 2 of unitaries.